# SectionList & Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

What is the proper way to type SectionList? I'm running into a bug where this works (from the [docs example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist)):

```
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item, index}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
          )}
          sections={ticksData}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        />;
```

But this doesn't:

```
const renderSectionHeader=({section: {title}}) => (
  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
 );

return (
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({item, index}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
          renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
          sections={ticksData}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        />;
```

I get this error:

> Types of property 'renderSectionHeader' are incompatible. Type '({ section: { title } }: { section: { title: any; }; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '(info: { section: SectionListData; }) => ReactElement'. Types of parameters '__0' and 'info' are incompatible. Type '{ section: SectionListData; }' is not assignable to type '{ section: { title: any; }; }'. Types of property 'section' are incompatible. Type 'SectionListData' is not assignable to type '{ title: any; }'. Property 'title' is missing in type 'SectionListData'.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, came to this answer but there was no solution yet, so here is mine:

```
import { SectionList, SectionListData } from 'react-native';

interface IHeader {
  section: SectionListData<{ title: string }>
}

const renderSectionHeader=({section: {title}}: IHeader) => (
  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
);
```